# ActiveMQ messaging scope

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

We are creating a new project that consists of:
3 separate web applications (wars), JMS - activeMQ, Spring and tomcat clustering that are running all of the web apps (each).

I can think of 3 different scope for messages to be delivered:

1) From within the web application (i.e. from service1 to service2)

2) From One web application to another (i.e. one war to another)

3) From one web server to another (i.e. tomcat1 to tomcat2)

Does activeMQ support all of the above? How does the configuration for each scenario varies from on another? (in regards to spring configuration maybe?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ tends to be run externally from the systems that use it. In other words, as a standalone server process - a tier, in the same way that a database is a tier of your application.

So you might have multiple web servers communicating between each other through the one ActiveMQ broker. As such, it can easily support all 3 of the use cases that you have described. If you are new to ActiveMQ, I recommend that you read ActiveMQ In Action, as it covers this topic extremely well and will help you to understand how to work with it.